# TinyMCE steals the focus when calling execCommand

Tags: tinymce, focus, execcommand

I have a bunch of inputs on my HTML page, plus a textarea which is replaced by a TinyMCE editor. There are various scenarios where this page is loaded and every time one of the inputs must get the focus. But when the TinyMCE is initialized, it just steals the focus. I narrowed down the problem to an execCommand call which sets the default font size in TinyMCE.

The issue can be reproduced in this simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',
                setup: function(editor) {
                    editor.on('init', function() {
                        this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "14pt"); // <<---- This line causes the TinyMCE editor to steal the focus!
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="inp" />
        <textarea>Hello, World!</textarea>
        
        <script>
            document.getElementById("inp").focus();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge, and the same issue happened in all of them. Any idea how I can prevent this? I do not want to set the focus again once the TinyMCE is done initializing, since at that point the page has scrolled to the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I said I did not want to set the focus "again" once the TinyMCE is done initialization, but I ended up doing something similar to that. Instead of setting the focus at the bottom of the page, I moved the code inside the tinymce.init and also called $(document).scrollTop(0);. Here is the code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function() {
            this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "14pt"); // <<---- This line causes the TinyMCE editor to steal the focus!
                        
            // Scroll to the top of the page.
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
            // Now set the focus.
            document.getElementById("inp").focus();
        });
    }
});
```

I believe there is a bug in TinyMCE and I hope it gets fixed in one of the future revs. I also hope this workaround helps someone down the road.

Comment: You might want to use `init_instance_callback` because it will be called after the TinyMCE editor has been fully rendered whereas `setup` is called before rendering the editor for the first time. In case some of the rendering code moves focus around, it may be set incorrectly if you set the focus in `setup`.

Answer (score 0):

While you are issuing the command to change the font size, *you aren't actually setting a default font in the TinyMCE editor*. You are firing those commands, but if there is any content to be loaded into the editor, it won't have this font information applied.

To set default font information in TinyMCE use CSS, either via the `content_css` or `content_style` configuration options:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

Here are examples that show the differences between the two approaches.

In this example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/oAhaab

...commands to set the default font family and size are issued, but they **aren't applied** to the content that is then loaded into the editor. They are fired, but don't end up applying to content loaded into the editor.

Whereas,in this example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/nAhaab

...the default font information is applied to loaded content via CSS as expected.

Comment: Thanks. But the font itself is not that important. I can use whatever the default font is, but the size is important. We have a large number of senior users that would prefer to have a much larger font size and do not want to change it every time they write a message. So they set the preferred font size in their profiles, and we use that size as the default. Plus, setting the font name does not solve the "focus" issue. But thanks for spending the time to respond to my question. Cheers! :)

Comment: I used font name in addition to font size for demonstration purposes only. You don't have to include font name. However, the point still stands, the method you are using to set default font size will not work if any content is loaded into the editor. Setting font size via content_css or content_style will solve that issue.

Comment: I do not want to change the font size of the existing text. I only want the new text entered by the user to use the default size that I'm setting. And it works just fine, except for the focus issue which is now fixed with the workaround I mentioned above. Am I still missing something? :)

Comment: same problem i have

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late to the party, but since I encountered the same issue with unwanted scrolling after executing an editor command, I would offer another alternative to prevent tinyMCE from stealing the focus.

Technically I do not "prevent" tinyMCE from getting or better "stealing" focus, but I'd rather blur it immediately.

Like so:

```
const defaultFontSize = "12pt";

setup: (editor) => {
   editor.on("init", () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
         editor.blur();
         editor.execCommand("fontSize", false, defaultFontSize);
      }, 0);
   });
};
```

The setTimeout function with a delay of 0ms starts a new macrotask on the event-queue and is crutial to give the browser a chance to complete its focus changes before executing the subsequent commands)